# In Python pandas, why would one use pivot() over pivot_table()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have read many information about the difference between the `pivot_table()` and `pivot()`, what I got is that it seems like the `pivot_table()` is more powerful and can perform more calculations over the `pivot()`.

Is that correct? if so, is that mean `pivot_table()` can fully replace the `pivot()` and one should always go for using the `pivot_table()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency might be a concern: [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) has a simpler code and is thus faster than [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

Comparison on a perfect N*N long input reshaped into a square DataFrame:

[image]

Used inputs and reshaping code:

```
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(product(range(N), range(N), [1])

df.pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2)

df.pivot_table(index=0, columns=1, values=2)
```

Comment: Thanks mozway. I was also thinking the efficiency could be a key difference but not sure how's the actual difference in performance would be.